# The right way to create a reminder workflow at suitecrm?

Tags: php, workflow, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to create a reminder workflow at suitecrm. 
The reminder workflow should send a warning email to my email address if my "ticket module" (a module i built using module builder)'s "status" field stays pending for two days

I followed the link [(here)](https://suitecrm.com/wiki/index.php/Userguides#Cases_Reminder) exactly like it says.

My Workflow conditions are:

1- Date modified greater than (Now - 2 days)

2- Status is pending.

My action is ( send email to my email address).
the Repeated Run is NOT checked as requested at the above link.

The problem is the workflow never waits for two days,it sends the email as soon as i add a new record to the selected module.

I also tried a new condition  (Now + 2 days) just in case, and same problem happens.

Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

here are some information that may help

-Suitecrm version is Version 7.1.4,Sugar Version 6.5.18 (Build 1110)
-I created the cron job to run the cron.php every 1 minute  as requested by Suitecrm

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was told to changed the operator to "Less than or equal" instead of "greater than"" and it works fine right now. 
thx